# UnmarshalException : camel soap unmarshaling error unexpected element

Tags: apache, soap, apache-camel, spring-camel, cxf-codegen-plugin

[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; unexpected element (uri:"http://service.example.com/", local:"custDetails"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body>,<{}Customer>,<{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope>,<{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault>,<{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Header>]

**Problem statement**: Camel is not expecting to receive the custDetails (webmethod) and the namespace.
**Expectation** : to use camel-soap to unmarshal the payload to soapJaxb out of the box.

1. Generated JAXB classes using maven-jaxb2-plugin for the xsd below. Results produced three classes with annotations -  Customer.java, ObjectFactory,java , Order.java.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          elementFormDefault="qualified" 
          attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
          >
   <xs:element name="Customer">
   <xs:complexType >
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="ListOfOrders" type="order" minOccurs="0" />
   </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:complexType name="order">
   <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="ProductName" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="ListOfDevice" minOccurs="0" >
           <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="DeviceName" type="xs:string"/>
                   <xs:element name="ManufactureDate" type="xs:date"/>
               </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   </xs:schema>
   ```
2. Expose webservice custDetails(..) as follows using cxf endpoint with DataFormat set to PAYLOAD. [**UPDATED with @Configuration**]

   ```
       @Configuration
      public class WebServiceConfig {
        @Autowired 
       private Bus bus;

       @Bean 
       public CxfEndpoint getCustomerDetails() {
           CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
           cxfEndpoint.setAddress("/customerProvide");
           cxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(CustomerSvc.class);
           cxfEndpoint.setBus(bus);
           cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.PAYLOAD);return cxfEndpoint ;}

       @Webservice
       public interface CustomerSvc {
       @WebMethod
       Customer  custDetails ( @WebParam(name="Customer")Customer Customer ) ;}

       // Simple route in Route class.
       @Component
       public class CustomerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
         public void configure (){
       SoapJaxbDataFormat soapDF 
       = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("com.example.service", new TypeNameStrategy());

        from("cxf:bean:getCustomerDetails").unmarshal(soapDF)
       .log("receive : ${body}")
       }
   ```
3. Wsdl generated and imported to soapUI. sample SOAPUI request to test is as follows.

   ```
   <soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:ser="http://service.example.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ser:custDetails>
        <ser:Customer>
           <Id>1-abc</Id>
           <Address>23 Sydney Oxley road</Address>
           <ListOfOrders>
              <Id>P1344</Id>
              <ProductName>DRAM</ProductName>
              <ListOfDevice>
                 <DeviceName>20nm</DeviceName>
                 <ManufactureDate>15-8-2017</ManufactureDate>
              </ListOfDevice>
           </ListOfOrders>
        </ser:Customer>
     </ser:custDetails>
    </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```
4. When I try to unmarshal PAYLOAD with soap dataformat, camel is throwing an error. It is the hitting namespace error. I am not sure why package-info class is not generated. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
5. UPDATE, wsdl given below.
       `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://service.example.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="CustomerSvcService" targetNamespace="http://service.example.com/">
         <wsdl:types>
       <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://service.example.com/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://service.example.com/">
         <xs:element name="Customer">
           <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ListOfOrders" type="tns:order"/>
             </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:complexType name="order">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="ProductName" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ListOfDevice">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="DeviceName" type="xs:string"/>
                   <xs:element name="ManufactureDate" type="xs:date"/>
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="custDetails" type="tns:custDetails"/>
         <xs:complexType name="custDetails">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Customer"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="custDetailsResponse" type="tns:custDetailsResponse"/>
         <xs:complexType name="custDetailsResponse">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Customer"/>
           </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
       </xs:schema>
         </wsdl:types>
         <wsdl:message name="custDetails">
           <wsdl:part element="tns:custDetails" name="parameters">
           </wsdl:part>
         </wsdl:message>
         <wsdl:message name="custDetailsResponse">
           <wsdl:part element="tns:custDetailsResponse" name="parameters">
           </wsdl:part>
         </wsdl:message>
         <wsdl:portType name="CustomerSvc">
           <wsdl:operation name="custDetails">
             <wsdl:input message="tns:custDetails" name="custDetails">
           </wsdl:input>
             <wsdl:output message="tns:custDetailsResponse" name="custDetailsResponse">
           </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
         </wsdl:portType>
         <wsdl:binding name="CustomerSvcServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:CustomerSvc">
           <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="custDetails">
             <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
             <wsdl:input name="custDetails">
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:input>
             <wsdl:output name="custDetailsResponse">
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
             </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
         </wsdl:binding>
         <wsdl:service name="CustomerSvcService">
           <wsdl:port binding="tns:CustomerSvcServiceSoapBinding" name="CustomerSvcPort">
             <soap:address location="http://localhost:12000/services/customerProvide"/>
           </wsdl:port>
         </wsdl:service>
       </wsdl:definitions>`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT due to updated question**

You try to unmarshal the request payload with Jax-B based on the XML schema you posted at the top of your question.

But in this schema **the element `custDetails` does not exist**. It exists in the schema part of your WSDL, but not in the schema?!? Therefore the error `unexpected element`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I think the wsdl generated is correct. if observe point 2 above,                     
  we got @webmethod custDetails resulting the wsdl section   <wsdl:portType name="CustomerSvc">
    <wsdl:operation name="custDetails">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:custDetails" name="custDetails">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:custDetailsResponse" name="custDetailsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

Comment: I begin to think that testing with soapUI is not feasible

Comment: SoapUI is quite popular for testing web services, this should work fine. For further details you would need to add the WSDL to your question. Otherwise it is impossible to see how the request must look like. The `wsdl:operation` element references a message `tns:custDetails`, and a `wsdl:message` element defines that message.

Comment: it have tried these and it does not work. I am curious to why it fails. when I do not wrap it with a camel route, everything works perfectly. Also if set the CxfEndpoint to POJO mode it works and binds the body of message correctly to the customer class. – Nahfees 13 mins ago

Comment: I don't know code-first web services very good, but obviously the request wrapper element is the problem. Not sure if the `@RequestWrapper` annotation could help in this case. But however, in payload mode you simply get the `soap:Body` content as XML (including `custDetails` element and you can't unmarshal it with Jax-B when the `custDetails` element is not part of the known types. You would have to "unpack" the Customer element first. In POJO mode CXF also handles the body and it knows the `custDetails` element from the WSDL.